# Is it possible that a hosting service is not supporting media query in CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress, hosting, responsive

I'm working with a client using MeccaHosting for her website. I'm coding the site with Wordpress. Everything looks fine on Chrome, from regular site to mobile site simulated by Chrome locally when I set up with MAMP. However, when I uploaded the site, I noticed that a lot of the media query definitions in CSS are not inherited or recognized. For example, I have the 12-grid columns for the site.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 769px) {
.page-template-services .three-fourths {
   width: 100%;
   margin-left: 0;
   margin-right: 0;
}  
.page-template-services .one-fourth {
   width: 80%;
   margin-left: 0;
}
```

And it's not recognized in the iPad or Chrome iPad simulator. Is it possible that the media query needs different format because it's a different hosting service? I never had issues with this with GoDaddy.

I'm using the same Chrome browser with regular site and mobile site simulation. It looks very different. Is it possible that it's the hosting service issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Anything is possible. It's very likely, your shared hosting account is loaded up and you are experiencing lag or even a cache issue. If it works locally, on MAMP, like you say, than it'll work when your site is live.

Always double-check and make sure you are testing in Private Browser - CTRL + SHIFT + N in Chrome. You get what you pay for, right? $2 a month hosting is a bad idea in my opinion.